# What do you call the act of throwing something continuously?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I am not sure if there's a good phrase or word for this? I am thinking maybe using the word "threw bits by bits", but I am sure there are better sounding words. I want to sound like a native English speaker, so I would rather not use an awkward sounding phrase.

For example:

> He threw some bit of bread bits by bits so that he could find his way
>   back in the forest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a word or phrase with quite the meaning you suggest. One might use "piece by peice" but that does quite give the impression i think you want. "bit by bit" means a small section or element at a time, as in "they solved the problem bit by bit" or "I couldn't handle the task all at once, but bit by bit I got it done." One might say:

> He tossed a series of pieces of bread to the side so that the could find his way back.

or perhaps

> He left a trail of pieces of bread so that the could find his way back.

One could speak of 'throwing a stream of" something, perhaps rocks, but that would suggest something that was truly continuous, with almost no pauses between items, which I don't think was your intended meaning.